# What is the best way of getting inner select part from a view create script provided by sp_helptext?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-function

i have a view and i want its inner select part which is `SELECT 12345` in my case.

My view is like below:

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
SELECT 12345
```

If i use sp_helptext, it returns me all script including CREATE VIEW ...

How can i get only inner select part of it?

Using regular expression? If so, how? If not, what would you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need a query to retrieve this? Hopefully you aren't writing code that needs to dissect a view on a regular basis.

Comment: I will use it in a join statement like INNER JOIN (SELECT 12345). It cannot be used like INNER JOIN myView.  Because my view script is complex and contains some texts which i want to replace like {0}. i need to take view script, replace values and use it in a joined final query.

Comment: Sounds to me like you just need to write your new query and not try to join to the view definition with replace statements and such going on. This sounds like a very brittle implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
USE myDB
GO

SELECT SUBSTRING(definition,(CHARINDEX('AS',definition)+2),LEN(definition)) FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('myView')
```

Comment: The view name itself can contain 'AS' characters, so this does not sound like a good idea :S

Comment: Yes, that's true. Can not be considered as a generic solution. Thanks for pointing that out.